# Remove into tags jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to cut/paste text between `<br>` and `</small>` in a div tag in jQuery ?

```
<small>Price for one. <br> Price for two.</small>
```

my Div

```
<div id="try"></div>
```

Comment: which one??? Price for one. Or, Price for two????? Post your code that you've tried so far...

Comment: $("small").html().split("<br>")[1] ?

Comment: `var small=document.getElementsByTagName('small'),i=0;while(i<small.length){var tempHTML=small[i].innerHTML;var spliteHTML=tempHTML.split('<br>');document.getElementById("try").innerHTML=spliteHTML[spliteHTML.length-1];i++;}`... for those who love `the speed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You you want to cut/paste, you can access the text node and then append it to the div like

```js
$('#try').append($('small br').prop('nextSibling'))
```

```css
small {
  color: red;
}
div {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<small>Price for one. <br> Price for two.</small>
<div id="try"></div>
```

Comment: @BhojendraSah `text between <br> and </small>`

Comment: @BhojendraSah , if he *specifically* says `between <br> and </small>` what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Good. But could you please explain .prop() part that is selecting the text next to br? I've seen using prop for it's property, but not like you're using...

Comment: @BhojendraSah else we need to access the dom node and then access the nextSibling like `$('small br')[0].nextSibling`... prop also does the same...

Comment: ummm, every element have dom tree property in them?

Comment: Thats exactly that, thanks. (By the way my post was totally clear thanks for bad marks...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    var html=$('small').html();
    $('#try').html(html.split('<br>')[1]);
});
```